# PowerBI drill through report issue

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

While going to drill through report  from Original report we can see certain dataset based on the condition. But next time when we directly try to access the same drill through report, it shows the data that was rendered last time. Is there any way where we can see the drill through report without any kind of filtering if we try to access it directly?

Answer (score 0):

Power BI has the option to retain the last used state of the report, this can be reset, using the option 'Reset to default' in the Power BI Service. You can turn off the option when loading the report to the service so it always retains the default state when going back to the report, it is in the report options in Power BI Desktop.

For a full outline of persistent filters, how to reset, or deactivate them please read the [MS Docs on the topic](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-persistent-filters-in-the-service/).

Comment: Thanks for the option.I am validating this option as i am dealing with a matrix data form.

Comment: This solution did not work. My requirement was clearing the filter for my drill through report, so when next time someone opens the drill through report directly, he should not see the data that came at the last filtering condition.